# Are 400 and 45 correct for CD and VL in roman,respectively?

Tags: notation

can VL and CD be roman numerals for 45 and 400 respectively? By the way,I already tried CCCC for 400.

Comment: 45 is XLV and 400 is indeed CD. About whether CCCC is acceptable, I have seen IIII used for IV but am not clear on the (acceptable exceptions to the) rules.

Comment: CD is right, but VL is not. Subtractions are only used for subtracting one power of ten from five times as much, or ten times as much. As another example 1999 is MCMXCIX, not MIM. IIII for IV is only used on clocks.

Comment: Ah OK, IIII seems to be an isolated thing, and it appears it was introduced much later. See [here](http://www.ubr.com/clocks/frequently-asked-questions-faq/faq-roman-iiii-vs-iv-on-clock-dials.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

$400$ would be $CD$ ($500-100$), the same way $4$ is $IV$ ($5-1$)

$45$ is $XLV$ ($(50-10)+5$).

$CCCC$ would probably be understandable (it has been shown that some less educated romans used $VIIII$ for nine instead of $IX$), but it is not the appropriate way to write it.

[Roman numbers from 1 to 500](http://romannumerals.babuo.com/roman-numerals-1-500)

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "it has been shown ..."?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Unfortunately now, I remember hearing it in history class.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Something like that http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/438/why-do-clocks-with-roman-numerals-use-iiii-instead-of-iv

Answer (score -1):

Yes CD is the Roman numeral for 400 but for 45 it's XLV